# Как получить и изменить переменную из другого класса?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В первом классе есть переменная `check`, которая при старте игры меняет значение с 0 на 1.

Второй класс предназначен для действий при столкновении игрока с объектом: отключается игровая сцена, включается сцена проигрыша, и для отключения спавна объектов нужно вернуть переменной `check` значение 0.

Пробовал вот так, но значение переменной не меняется.

```
Class1 class = new Class1();
class.check = 0;
```

Как можно это провернуть?

Comment: То есть вы создаёте новый объект, меняете у него значение и не понимаете, почему это же поле не изменилось у первого объекта?

Comment: Сейчас я уже понял, что это не подойдёт. Но всё же, как поступить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная естественно должна быть public, но у вас похоже так и есть.
Скрипт с этой переменной висит на каком-то объекте? Теоретически, должен. Если висит, то получить переменную можно так:
`[Объект, на котором висит скрипт с переменной check].GetComponent<Class1>().check`

То есть мы берем объект, получаем класс Class1 и переменную check.